# Populate new rank field with custom order

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to populate a new Rank field in my table. Here is an example of how it should look like.

```
+-----------+------------+------+
| CountryId | CreateDate | Rank |
+-----------+------------+------+
|         1 | 2020-01-01 |    4 |
|         1 | 2020-02-01 |    3 |
|         1 | 2020-02-01 |    2 |
|         1 | 2020-03-01 |    1 |
|         2 | 2020-01-01 |    1 |
|         2 | 2020-02-01 |    2 |
|         3 | 2020-01-01 |    1 |
+-----------+------------+------+
```

So the Rank field has to be populated by count of `CountryId` and ordered by `CreateDate`, so the newest record has the highest rank (lowest number).

**Note**: It can happen that `CreateDate` is same for two records, in that case the `Rank` should still increment.

Code:

```sql
with rankUpdate as (
      select t.*,
             DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CountryId order by CreatedDate) AS NewRank
      from Countries t
     )
update rankUpdate
     set [Rank] = NewRank;
```

Comment: RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CountryId ORDER BY CreationDate DESC)

Comment: @McNets The issue with same Date still persist.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a scenario that isn't in your example data--which makes it hard for folks to handle that in answers. It sounds like you're saying that within the country partitions, the date is duplicated, and when that happens, you want the `rank` to remain unique? Please add that scenario to your data set.

Comment: Then use ROW_NUMBER() https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aa451a749e566bcfe4ba9f1a3d522a12

Comment: @AMtwo Yes, date is the same.
While writing this question, I wanted to write that I found the ROW_NUMBER to fix my issue.

Comment: @McNets Tnx, a couple minutes ago I tried with ROW_NUMBER and it seems it sets the data correclty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with rows that are "tied" during ranking, there are multiple desired outcomes.

`RANK` will assign "tied" rows the same number, then leave a gap. (Ex 1,2,2,4,4,6,7...)

`DENSE_RANK` will also assign "tied" rows the same number, but leave no gaps. (Ex 1,2,2,3,3,4,5)

`ROW_NUMBER` will assign consecutive increasing numbers with no gaps. When two values are "tied" it will randomly determine the order. Note that the randomness is non-deterministic. It might return the same "random" order 10000 times in a row, then suddenly re-order the way it numbers tied rows.

It sounds like you are looking for `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
select t.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CountryId order by CreatedDate) AS NewRank
from Countries t
```

If there's a secondary criteria that can be used as a tie-breaker, you can always add the second column to the `ORDER BY`. In `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` it can minimize the number of ties, and in `ROW_NUMBER` it can improve determinism.